# How would I define route to get me to a specific section on page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've a Register link on menu bar. On register page I have 2 forms, Login and Signup.
By default, it shows the Login form but I want it to show the Signup form first.

I thought If I do it with route by giving an Id to my signup form then I would be able to do that.
But it's giving me the error by saying

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: getRegister]
```

How would I modify my route?

Route

```
   Route::get('/registration{url}',  [
        'uses' => 'niceActionController@getRegister',
        'as' => 'getRegister'
    ]);
```

Controller

```
public function getRegister($url)
{
    return view( '/' . $url,  ['url' => $url]);
}
```

Header

```
<a href="{{route('getRegister',['url'=> '#register_forms']) }}">{{ __('Register')}}</a>
```

Comment: `/registration{url}` will be `/registration/{url}`

Comment: @sta Not resolved !
Still the same error :(

Comment: Try without slash, 
on your address bar `127.0.0.1:8000/registration/register_forms`

Comment: @sta
View [.register_forms] not found.

Comment: I did 127.0.0.1:8000/registration/#register_forms and it returns 404 | Page Not Found

Comment: That means `.register_forms.blade.php` is not found on your `views` dir. Remove the dot (**.**) and create a page on `.../views/register_forms.blade.php`

Comment: @sta my blade name is "register" and "register_forms" is the form Id that I want it to hit on page load. Hope you understand now

Comment: If I use /register, it returns laravel default registration page that's why I changes the url for this blade like /registration

Comment: After doing what @sta suggested, you can run `php artisan config:cache` and try again.

Comment: May be you can't. It's browser navigation thing and it never hits the server. If you hit `domain.com/registration/#register_forms` then the browser will hit `domain.com/registration/` Browser take `#register_forms` as an html `id` element. `id="register_forms`

Comment: @AbdellahRamadan Done but still the issue exist

Comment: @sta You are right but what should I do here now.
I have applied your suggested snippets but nothing worked :(. 
I have  a simple Register page with URL /registration and I want it to show the section on this page with id #register_forms when someone hit the URL. This is my problem!

Comment: Can you tell me,  why you need the `registration/{url}`, {url} param in your route? Even its static too, not dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use the #url parameter in your web routes and controller, it is not meant for the backend.

```
Route::get('registration', ['niceActionController::class, 'getRegister'])->name('getRegister');
```

`{{route('getRegister')}}` will print out the link to the page, you'll want to put you parameter after the route, it will be handled after your page has loaded.

```
<a href="{{route('getRegister')}}#register_forms">{{ __('Register')}}</a>
```

in your controller you put the name of your blade template (not a route)

```
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('nameofthetemplate');
}
```

Comment: Perfect Approach !
Worked for me :)

Comment: @MrEvers  
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865

Answer (score 1):

1. Define your routes as below.

   `Route::get('action/{action_type}', 'NiceActionController@action') ->where('action_type', 'login|register') ->name("action");`
2. In the view you can get route as below

   `{{route('action', ['action_type' => 'register'])}}`
   *OR*
   `{{route('action', ['action_type' => 'login'])}}`
3. In the controller you can access the action_type parameter value as below.

   `$request->action_type;`

   *Make sure you add `Request $request` parameter in method*

***Note***:
*The hash value is not accessible by the server script. You can either append action type in URL as shown in the above sample or include it in the query string. Check below link check how to get query string parameter value.*
*https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request*

***Tip**: Please try to follow the Laravel naming conventions.*

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your route

```
<a href="{{route('getRegister', '#register_forms') }}">{{ __('Register')}}</a>
```

```
Route::get('/registration/{url}',  [
        'uses' => 'niceActionController@getRegister',
        'as' => 'getRegister'
    ]);
```

```
public function getRegister($url)
{
    return view( viewNameHere,  ['url' => $url]);
}
```

Comment: Should I keep my Route simple without any parameter ?

Comment: @Shaan ```#register_forms``` is the parameter on the above `route`

Comment: This is how my URL is showing now
http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration?#register_forms but it's not showing the desired section.

Comment: Now it's showing this after update my code. 
Missing required parameters for [Route: getRegister] [URI: registration/{url}].

Comment: @Shaan I tried a simulation of your code and it works for me using the above snippet.

Comment: @Shaan also, looking at your `getRegister` function seems to be returning a url rather than a view name. See my updated answer.

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: getRegister] [URI: registration/{url}].. LOL

Comment: @Abdellah Ramadan  
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865

Answer (score 0):

> Because **#** symbol isn't parsed by the server, it's used by the browser for on-page navigation.

You might be familar with CSS/JS. **#** links in URLs will take you to either a named tag or **ID** tag in the page (e.g. http://page.com/#tag will take you to an element with the ID "tag")

When you hit http://page.com/registration/#register_forms the browser hit the page http://page.com/registration/ and searching for the `id="register_forms"` on your HTML.

Comment: I know that but where to add #. I tried to insert it into my Route like this    Route::get('/registration#login_form', function () {} but it says "Page Not Found"

Comment: Route will be `Route::get('/registration', function ().…` in your anchor link it will be `127.0.0.1:8000/regiatration#login_form`

Comment: @sta  
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865